# Can a field be added to component state from a class function in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have come across some confusing behaviour in a React JS project that I am maintaining.

There is a class, CostCalculator, with the following constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Trade: {
            AccountType: 1,
            Stock: "",
            Price: 0.0,
            Quantity: 0
        },
        TradeCost: null
    };
```

The CostCalculator component renders a subcomponent, TradeDetails, which is an input form for the fields necessary to compute the cost.  The Trade state object and a handleOnChange function gets sent down as props for TradeDetails.

```
<TradeDetails
    Trade={this.state.Trade}
    handleOnChange={this.handleOnChange}
/>
```

The TradeDetails form has some input fields:

```
...

<FormGroup controlId="trade_AccountNumber">
    <Col sm={4}> Account Number </Col>
    <Col sm={8}>
       <FormControl
           type="text"
           placeholder="Account Number"
           value={this.props.Trade.AccountNumber}
           onChange={this.props.handleOnChange}
       />
    </Col>
</FormGroup>
<FormGroup controlId="trade_AssetClass">
    <Col sm={4}> Asset Class  </Col>                            
    <Col sm={8}>
        <FormControl
            componentClass="select"
            placeholder="Account Type"
            value={this.props.Trade.AccountType}
            onChange={this.props.handleOnChange}
        >
            <option value="1">Type 1</option>
            <option value="2">Type 2</option>
            <option value="3">Type 3</option>
        </FormControl>
    </Col>
</FormGroup>

...
```

Some of the input fields correspond to fields in the Trade prop, but others, for example AccountNumber above, are not in the props.  In the CostCalculator component, the handleOnChange function assigns the input event values to the state like so:

```
handleOnChange = event => {
    var targetId = event.target.id;
    var targetValue = event.target.value;
    var fieldName = "";
    if (fieldName === "Account type") {
        this.setState({
                Trade: {
                    ...this.state.Trade,
                    Account type: targetValue
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
    } 
    else if (fieldName === "Other fields")
        ... 
};
```

And similarly for the other fields.
Interestingly, there is no test for when the field name is AccountNumber, and AccountNumber is also not part of the state.  The confusing thing is, though, when logging after form submission:

```
console.log("Account number: "+ this.state.Trade.AccountNumber);
```

The statement logs the value filled into the form field, even though, according to the class definition, there is no Trade.AccountNumber state in the component.

Did the handleOnChange method add a field to the state?  If not, how can this behaviour be explained?

Comment: what does the `onChange` look like for the `<FormControl />` component?

Comment: What is your entire handlechange method and why do you have a separate check

Comment: You can add anything to state, no need for it to exist in the constructor definition.

What does the ```else``` branch do in ```handleOnChange```?

Maybe it acts like a catch-all, similar to this, for values that don't need special attention: 

```this.setState({ Trade: { ...this.state.Trade, [event.target.id]: event.target.value } });```

Comment: The else clause in the handleOnChange function:   `else {
    this.setState({
     Trade: {
      ...this.state.Trade,
      ...this.stateObject(fieldName, targetValue)
     }
    });
   }`  The stateObject function is this: 

 `stateObject = (fieldName, targetValue) => {
  var returnObj = {};
  returnObj[fieldName] = targetValue;
  return returnObj;   
 };`

Comment: It's doing the same thing without fancy features than. So if a fieldName doesn't have a special case handled by an ```if``` branch, it just gets saved in ```state.Trade```.